# Where to point msedge binary location when tests are in azure pipeline?

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-pipelines

I have set up selenium tests to run in Azure pipelines, the solution I use, takes different versions of `.runsettings` files, one for chrome and one for edge, the chrome tests are working well but the edge tests seem to be falling over as it can't find the msedge binary location. I have tried to define it as being in the same place as on my machine:

> C://Program Files (x86)Microsoft//Edge//Application//MicrosoftEdge.exe

This hasn't worked so I'm not sure if I need to install a capability to the agent, or if I need to adjust where I'm pointing to

Comment: there are several ways to run Edge in C#. e.g. `Process.Start("cmd", $"/c start microsoft-edge:http://localhost");` or `Process.Start("shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's useful to know a few debug commands you can throw on the agent to find out these kinds of things.

```
C:
Dir /b /s MicrosoftEdge.exe
```

From a script task should be able to find it anywhere on C.

Or using

```
Where MicrosoftEdge.exe
```

Assuming it's on the `%path%` somewhere...

Or using `reg.exe` to lift the location from the registry.

But in this case, I'm wondering whether it's simply the missing `\\`  after `(x86)`... Or possibly the fact that the executable got renamed with the release of edge chromium:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the new location didn't work but the debugging did!